# Mongoose: Is field set in the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema with a property that holds an array of strings. Something like:

```
var schema = mongoose.schema({
  myProp: [String]
})
mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);
```

Now, when I load a `MyModel` document and check its `.myProp` property, I get an empty array (thanks to Mongoose's casting, I think), even if the document in Mongo has no `myProp` field.

How can I distinguish from my javascript between the document in mongo having no `myProp` field, and having a `myProp` field whose value is an empty array, given that `doc.myProp` returns an empty array in both cases?

Comment: can you explain the use case where you would need to know whether or not the property exists? An empty array seems like a good enough indication to me, but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use the lean() option when querying, which returns exactly what is in Mongo without creating an instance of the Mongoose model.

```
Model.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
  // docs should be identical to your mongo collection
});
```

Comment: You can also return model.toObject() on your returned document, but I think the issue still remains, myProp will be an empty array. I don't believe mongoose will drop the property just because no value is specified. At least, I hope it wouldn't do something like this.